# Push transactions to Google Analytics using php

Tags: php, google-analytics, transactions, google-api, measurement-protocol

I need to push offline transactions to Google Analytics.

I am thinking of creating a php script that queries the ecommerce database looking at transactions made in the last hour created from the backend. Having identified these transactions (and line items/SKU's).

How do I use PHP to push data to Google Analytics?

Comment: Have you got any code to show?

Comment: No yet masteusz. I have a query that provides the dataset to generate 'fields' required for the transaction and item hits. I'm just not sure how to put them together to form an Analytics transaction hit via php. can you advise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go though the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en).  There is no client library to help you do this in PHP you will have to code it yourself.  That being said its not that hard its just a normal HTTP Post or HTTP Get request.  The trick is building up your requests correctly.

A couple of quick tips.

[Qt](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) stands for que time and will allow you to set the time that the hit arrived on your server.  Note it must not be greater than four hours ago.

While you are testing this you can use the [debug](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits) endpoint to validate your hits.  The hits wont be sent to Google but it will tell you if they are valid or not.

Comment: Thanks DaImTo - the note on Qt and debug is really appreciated! I am unsure how to do the HTTP Post - is it a curl operation?

Comment: Google is your friend :P http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request  sorry its been about 10 years since I have had the power of PHP So I am a little rusty give it a shot if it doesn't work create a new question with your errors.   I will spot it and see if I cant get the power of curl back :)

Answer (score 0):

Measurement Protocols as @DaImTo mentioned is the answer. make a try here replacing the UA Id -

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=transaction&ti=12345&ta=westernWear&tr=50.00&ts=32.00&tt=12.00&cu=EUR

You can use DIv tool to validate all your post requests.

(dont forget to enable - ecommerce from view settings in GA when testing on new account)